# SQL script to check a value then if found increment a field by a value of 1

Tags: sql, sum, case, temp-tables

Im trying to write a script that will pull the information from a table called 'bookings', this contains a column that gives the length of each booking called 'hours'. Values in this column are shown as 1.0 for 60 minutes, 0.75 for 45 minutes, 0.5 for 30 minutes for example. My script needs to count the amount of bookings of a particular length and return the value, so for example I am using a Sum and Case statment for each...

```
SUM(case when Hours = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as '60 Mins',

SUM(case when Hours = 0.75 then 1 else 0 end) as '45 Mins',

SUM(case when Hours = 0.5 then 1 else 0 end) as '30 Mins',

SUM(case when Hours = 0.25 then 1 else 0 end) as '15 Mins'
```

My problem is that I need to record bookings over 60 minutes and split them into one of these four groups, an example is 1.5 hours would need to add a value of +1 to the 60 minute case statement and also +1 count to the 30 minute case statement value,

The only way I could think of doing that is to create a temporary table with columns for 60, 45, 30 and 15 count values then update this table by +1 if a result is found, so 1.25 would then update #temptable column(60) +1 and column(15)+1. Not sure how to do this, help greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Simon

Comment: seems like a MOD function is what you want.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: SQL database version 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4a7cd/4). Hopefully that is enough to get you started.

```
select hours
       ,100*(hours - round(hours,0,1))
from table1
```

so your code would be something like

```
SUM(case when hours - round(hours,0,1) = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as '60 Mins',

SUM(case when hours - round(hours,0,1) = 0.75 then 1 else 0 end) as '45 Mins',

SUM(case when hours - round(hours,0,1) = 0.5 then 1 else 0 end) as '30 Mins',

SUM(case when hours - round(hours,0,1) = 0.25 then 1 else 0 end) as '15 Mins'
```

Comment: Thanks, seems like a really useful site and almost what I am trying to achieve I think. Will that script count a 1.5 hour booking and add a count to 60 minute column +1 and 30 minute column +1 if that makes sense?

Comment: OK, here is the revised fiddle that includes the hour block calculation. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bc43a/7

Comment: That is really clever and so close, thank you! It works for the bookings that are of length 1.25 1.5 etc perfectly. For the bookings that are 1 hours though, so for example 2 hours and 3 hours I have 223 in total that should fall under 60 minute column but the script is only showing 77.

Comment: In the sample, it is correctly calculating 24 hour blocks, so there must be something else going on in either your dataset or your query.

Comment: Are you using `sum(round(hours,0,1)) as hour_blocks` to calculate the hour blocks?

Comment: Hi, yeah I did try that but I think I know what is happening. For a booking that is 2 hours it is counting it as 1 as opposed to +2 to the 60 minutes column if that makes sense (split it into 2 60 minute values so it counts as +2) Same for the 3 hour booking. I had 3 of them which should count for +9 to the 60 minute column but only counts them as +3. I used your script in the following way with this also as the first line...select sum(case when hours - round(hours,0,1) = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as

Comment: `select sum(case when hours - round(hours,0,1) = 0 then 1 else 0 end)` will not give you the correct reslut. It returns a 1 regardless of the number of hours.
`sum(round(hours,0,1))` will give you the correct result.

Comment: only comes back as 77 hours if I use that. I have on my test data, 161 - 1 hour bookings, 1 x 1.5 hour booking and 44 1.5 hour bookings, 4 x 2 hour bookings and 3 x 2.5 hour booking and finally 3 x 3 hour bookings, so was hoping to get to the figure 229 for 60 minute blocks, if that makes sense. Thank you for you help again, very close. Figure work exactly correct for the .25, .5 and .75 just the 60 minute blocks

Comment: Thank you, your script was working. There was a booking overlapping the Sunday night Timeband into Monday, was throwing the results as it was counting it as minus figure of -158 hours. start was greater than the finish. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks again! Have ticked your answer